# std::map sequencing of operator[] and size()

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a `std::map` and trying to fill it with pairs `(name, id)`. The `id` field is simply generated from map's `size()`. Here's a simplified version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct A {
    std::string name;
    int id;
    A(const std::string &s) : name(s), id(-1) { }
};

class Database {
    std::map<std::string, int> ids;
public:
    void insert(A *item) {
        ids[item->name] = item->id = ids.size();
    }
    void dump() const {
        for (std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator i = ids.begin(); i != ids.end(); i++)
            std::cout << i->second << ". " << i->first << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **agrv) {
    A a("Test");
    Database db;
    db.insert(&a);
    db.dump();
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that different compilers treat the `ids[item->name] = item->id = ids.size()` part differently. Clang++ produces

```
item->id = ids.size(); // First item gets 0
ids[item->name] = item->id;
```

when g++ does something like

```
ids.insert(std::pair<std::string, int>(item->name, 0));
item->id = ids.size(); // First item gets 1
ids[item->name] = item->id;
```

So, is this code valid (from the STL perspective) or it is as evil as `i = ++i + ++i`?

Comment: If the id is simply an index, what is the point in placing the items into std::map ?
Why not simply store them into an std::vector or array[] and access them from the index later?

Comment: Change your insert function to take only a string, insert ids.size() directly into map, and return a reference to the item just inserted.

Comment: It's a mapping from name to index, not from index to name.

Comment: @Neil: That doesn't really solve anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ids[item->name] = item->id = ids.size();
```

Without a [sequence point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) separating the two calls, the compiler is free to evaluate `operator[]` and `size()` in any order it likes. There is no guarantee that `size()` will be called before `operator[]`.

Comment: And to answer his last question: the code is valid, but parts of the behavior is unspecified.  (And it's not as evil as `i = ++i + ++i`.)

Comment: Sequence points are so 2003.  Now we have *sequenced-before* ordering relationships... this example is *indeterminately sequenced*, but `i = ++i + ++i` is *unsequenced* and therefore more evil

Answer (score -1):

change  `ids[item->name] = item->id = ids.size();` to

```
item->id = ids.size();
ids[item->name] = item->id;
```